# printf doesn't return anything when using the Mac Terminal Utility

Tags: c, macos, gcc, printf

I wrote a small Hello World app.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
   printf("Hello World\n");


}
```

When I run

```
gcc fileName.c
```

nothing is returned to the terminal. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

gcc is the compiler. it outputs a file called `a.out` unless specified otherwise using the `-o` flag, for example `gcc -o myprogram fileName.c` which will create an executable called myprogram from the source myFile.c.

To run your program write: `./a.out` in the terminal

Answer (score 6):

To compile an executable, you need to run:

```
gcc fileName.c -o app
```

That will create an executable file named `app` in the current directory. You then run that executable with:

```
./app
```